# 500 process is not defined ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I am getting this problem every time I *import a lib* or when I use *puppeteer* and I don't know how to fix it. I am trying to get some data from LinkedIn using https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkedin-client
the code is easy:

```
import LinkedinClient from 'linkedin-client';
    async function getIt() {
        const session = supabase.auth.session();

        const tok = session?.provider_token;
        const token = JSON.stringify(tok);
        console.log(token);
        
        const client = new LinkedinClient(token);
        const data = await client.fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/in/some-profile/');
        console.log(data);
    }
```

at first it gives me this error:*Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.promisify" in client code*

after I install `npm i util` then it displays the following error:

**500 process is not defined ReferenceError: process is not defined**

Can you please let me know how to fix it?(I'm using sveltekit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library requires to be run on the server. It has be in a [server endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints), it cannot be in a component or a `load` function.

If this is already the case, this might be an issue with Vite trying to remove server dependencies. There is e.g. a plugin [`@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill`](https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins#esbuild-pluginsnode-globals-polyfill) which polyfills the `process` variable. It may also be necessary to list packages in [`resolve.alias`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) in the Vite config, to point to the Node modules.

Comment: you are correct ,I too found this to be the issue.however even when I put it in an endpoint it takes around 3 seconds to crawl the data ...

Comment: That is to be expected if the library is based on Puppeteer which scrapes the UI of the page rather than just getting the data directly.

Comment: how can I do that?can you please give me an I'm trying to build an open source platform for startup's matching founders,would appreciate your help

Comment: You presumably can't, that's the whole reason the library does it this way in the first place. If Linkedin does not offer a sufficient API, getting the data from the pages is the next best thing but might be slow.